# What's the script language inside kernel Makefile?

Tags: makefile

```
55 ifeq ("$(origin C)", "command line")
56   KBUILD_CHECKSRC = $(C)
57 endif
58 ifndef KBUILD_CHECKSRC
59   KBUILD_CHECKSRC = 0
60 endif
```

In normal bash,there's no keywords like `ifndef`...

Answer (score 11):

(GNU)-Make has it's own syntax and the `ifeq`, `ifndef`, `endif` are comming from there. See the [GNU Make Documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html).